# Load WooCommerce Products Quicker

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, woocommerce

I am loading in products using a custom query (here is the code for it)

```
/* Load The Beast Balls Category */
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'product_cat' => 'beast-balls',
    //'orderby' => 'date',
    //'order' => 'desc'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product-node cat-beast-balls" id="cat-beast-balls">
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

My problem is that the query grabs all of the products, and once it has done that it dumps them in the page.

Is there anyway to have them be dumped in the page one by one as they're loaded so that it appears as if they load quicker?

Comment: You mean load them via AJAX? There are tons of answers on this topic.

Comment: Hi Dingo_d I am actually loading them via AJAX at the moment. Can you help direct me to some of these answers? I can't seem to find them!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+AJAX+load

Comment: Output is being buffered by PHP, try using `flush()` after the `</div>` in the loop, that should help.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the [transient api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache the query results. But why are you querying 100 products outside the loop? Why not just view the term archive for beast balls? Or take advantage of pagination plus lazy load.

Comment: I only have 15 or so products, I just put 100 as I'm sure I wont ever have over 100. I'm basically making a custom 'front-page' that loads in all the products via category using AJAX. the reason I have to load them category by category is because I have a feature which sorts them (price, newness etc) but keeps them in their categorical order. Since I want them to all be loaded pagination is not needed

Comment: Set products per page to -1 to load all products regardless of the total.

Answer (score 0):

please use this plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/infinite-ajax-scroll-woocommerce/9343295) loading product display on the page
page refresh so display set product per page in plugin then after scrolling page then other product display by ajax.

Comment: Sorry I never asked to load products on scroll